# console.log in php backend

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
  I did also creating a different class. but still not working...

but if I place the  '<script>console.log("message here");</script>' will work..
```

//index.html
assuming that this is a complete code.

```
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

//post.php

    <?PHP 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        echo "<script>console.log('".$_POST['name']."');</script>";
    }
?>
```

my problem is , i cant use console.log in submitting a form.  but if I did this in redirection It will work..

The Function under my class is ...

```
public function console($data) { 
  if(is_array($data) || is_object($data)) { 
     echo("<script>console.log('".json_encode($data)."');</script>"); 
  } else {
     echo("<script>console.log('".$data."');</script>"); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: So is the problem you're having that your `console.log` isn't firing when you load it into the browser with PHP?

Comment: Perhaps input the `console.log` argument as String?

`echo '<script>console.log("'.$_POST['name'].'");</script>';`

Comment: not actually load the php.. but when I submitting a form.

Comment: <script>console.log(".$_POST['name'].");</script>   is working when I place in a index.html  but my problem is when I place this into the target of a form

Comment: @DonnieGallocantaJr. If you place the code directly in HTML it should work. I imagine it would not work within PHP because of the missing `"` around the String argument. In my previous comment I've included the necessary `"`.

Comment: thanks sir.. but I did that also.. still not working..  even I check the preserved logs in my browsers..

Comment: @DonnieGallocantaJr. View the source page and look at the generated JavaScript code. What does the look like?

Comment: sorry sir.. but, I am not allowed to post my actual code in my project..  i can only share the function under my class ....       public  function console($data) {
    if(is_array($data) || is_object($data))
 {
  echo("<script>console.log('".json_encode($data)."');</script>");
 } else {
  echo("<script>console.log('".$data."');</script>");
 }
}

Comment: sir Im sorry.. I only have 9 reputation cus im new here ing stack overlow.. can we discuss this in facebook?

Comment: So what is the purpose of doing the console log? Are you trying to see what variables were posted to PHP? If thats the case why not consider using `var_dump` or `print_r` in PHP.

Comment: for debugging purposes... to monitor a specific function, or a variable.. sorry its my firsttym to use PHP

Comment: thank you sir.. my problem solved

Answer (score 3):

It does not work within PHP because of the missing " around the String argument of `console.log`.

The output would've been

```
<script>console.log(name);</script>
```

instead of

```
<script>console.log("name");</script>
```

Solution

`echo '<script>console.log("'.$_POST['name'].'");</script>';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug or see the value that was posted from the front end to back end then you can simply use the chrome inspector.

1. Right click anywhere in browser and click `inspect element`.
2. click on `network` tab.
3. submit your form with desired values.
4. on the left click on the `post.php`.
5. Click on the `headers` on the right and scroll down to find `Form Data`.
6. You will have all your post variables listed there with respective values.

Comment: I did.. but the specific data will not show.. for example I submit a form, then under the target file, has the condition for example, I created a function has a name isContain(). 

$variable = $var->isContain();//$variable is a boolean

echo "<script>console.log('".$variable."');</script>";

but this is under the target file

Comment: As long as you have posted your form you should see the value in the inspector. What is the target file? is it `post.php`? Can you explain what you are actually trying to do here? Probably then I will be able to help you with that.

Comment: .. actually sir, im doing in post.php is my validation before i call the method for querying in the database.

Comment: If you want to see the value that was posted to the backend, you do not need to use `console.log`. It is function to debug javascript and not PHP. You can follow steps in my answer to see that value of all data that was posted to backend using your form. In network tab click in post.php then find form data. If you form data is not showing up there, then the issue is in your frontend. So simplify it, if you posted your form correctly the post data will show up in the network tab.

Comment: thank you for helping me.. I made already a solution.. I use cookie instead console.log .. for debuging only..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to debug the `$_POST` variable, If thats the case, then Please note, that `console.log()` is a frontend debugging tool used in `javascript`, and has nothing to do with `php`.

Few good way of checking the content of variables in `php`.

### 1. **`print_r`**

This will output the content of a variable that can be an `array`, `object` or `string` in a nice human readable format.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

### 2. **`var_dump`**

This will output the content of the variable with extra respective details  like `datatypes` and `length`.

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```